# Create an if statement when button is pressed in Swift

Tags: swift, if-statement, uibutton, xcode6

Hi Im trying to create an if statement that has one option if button nr 1 is pressed and one option when button nr 2 is pressed. Im working with Xcode 6 and swift.

Here's the code i've tried so far:

```
if myButton1.touchInside = true {
    //Do something
}else{
    //Do something else
}
```

Comment: What are `button nr 1` and `button nr s` ?

Comment: Sorry it's suppose to be "2" not "s", i've edited my question.

Comment: So, you have two different buttons ?

Comment: @JohanEnstam That still doesn't help identify the problem. What kind of objects are they? What's wrong with the code you have? Doesn't compile? Crashes? Are you seeing any errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would create separate IBActions for each button by control dragging from the storyboard to the appropriate view controller.

```
@IBAction func taskOne(sender: UIButton) {
    // do something
}

@IBAction func taskTwo(sender: UIButton) {
    // do something else
}
```

Or if the functions are adequately related, I would drag both buttons into the same action and use a switch statement as follows.

```
@IBAction func doSomething(sender: UIButton) {
    let propertyToCheck = sender.currentTitle!
    switch propertyToCheck {
        case: "caseOne"
            // do something
        case: "caseTwo"
            // do something else
        default: break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I gave it a try, but if it didn't helped you please review your question / code.

[image: Example]

- 1a. Select a Button ;
- 1b. Place the Button (and configure it as you wish) ;
- 2a. Access the last tab of the button (Connection inspector) ;
- 2b. Drag the `touchUpInside` to the relevant ViewController ;
- 2c. Give it a name and do what you want to do inside (call other methods, ...) ;
- Repeat for each buttons.

If you're looking to do it all programmatically (no storyboard or xib), once you created your button :

```
// Add a target to your button
yourButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

// Create the method you want to call (see target before)
func pressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    // do some stuff
    println("yourButton was pressed")
}
```